# r metafor: how to select the best meta-analytical model (fixed / mixed models)?

Tags: r, meta-analysis

My newbie question is how to select the best model including different types of moderator variables in fixed or mixed models. 
Here's some example data (from the package help):

```
data(dat.bcg)

### meta-analysis of the log relative risks using a random-effects model
res0 <- rma(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)

### mixed-effects model with absolute latitude as a moderator
res1 <- rma(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, mods = ~ ablat, data=dat.bcg)

### mixed-effects model with two moderators (absolute latitude and publication year)
res2 <- rma(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg,
           mods = ~ ablat + year, data=dat.bcg)

### mixed-effects model with two moderators (one of which is a factor)
res3 <- rma(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg,
           mods = ~ ablat + factor(alloc), data=dat.bcg)
```

Is it right to select the model simply using Akaike Information Criterion?

```
> AIC(res0, res1, res2, res3)
#      df      AIC
# res0  2 28.40474
# res1  3 22.17464
# res2  4 24.21375
# res3  5 24.79656
```

Finally, selecting model res2 for the lowest AIC value.

Answer (score 1):

The answer must depend on what your scientific hypothesis was as the three predictors you mention are of different types. Distance from the equator (ablat) was suggested as a possible influence on the effectiveness of the vaccine so has a real scientific interest. Publication year (year) might suggest that the effectiveness was changing over time or more likely that studies were becoming better controlled. Allocation to treatment type (alloc) is a study quality variable. If you pick the model with the lowest AIC you risk missing important facts about the vaccine.

Comment: I understand your point, but I only used that example without considering the meaning of the moderators... I wonder which is the best model in statistical terms.

Comment: @Juanchi What exactly do you mean by "best model in statistical terms"?

Comment: The "best" model should not be confused with the other models not being useful. Moreover, imagine a significant effect of whatever on the odds of developing a disease. However, this models AIC difference between lowest AIC is only 1.95 lower (2 as the general guideline). I would hope that AIC would not exclusively guide your inference in this situation.

Comment: @Wolfgang In my real dataset I have 4 potential moderator variables and I don't really know how to select the final model for a best estimation of the effect sizes.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:model_selection_with_glmulti Note also the comment by @D_Williams - so you may want to use multimodel inference.

Comment: You do not say how many studies you have but you may like to have a look at [this study](http://systematicreviewsjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/2046-4053-2-107) which suggests that the ability to detect moderator effects relies on having either many studies or precise estimates from fewer studies.

Comment: Yes Wolfgang, that's what I'm looking for.  @D_Williamsalso gave me a good advice, I will have in mind to select the model.